# Javascript or HTML5 PDF Editor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, pdf-generation

I am looking for a component that will allow the user to  edit PDF files within an ASP.NET web page.

It is mainly going to be used as a template editor to add blocks/form fields mainly to an existing PDF. It should have rulers etc.. within it.

I have been searching for such a component for a while now and have drawn a blank.

A finished component would be ideal or at least some pointers on how to go about it.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reasonably certain that there is no product that does this off-the-shelf.

Without writing the solution yourself, you will likely not find any web-editors that allow uploading and then editing a PDF on your server. Decent desktop PDF editors are generally expensive, and I imagine the security woes surrounding PDFs would make this a complex solution

As for approaches, there are ASP.NET products that will generate a pdf from text or a document. Depending on your needs this might be acceptable. You could possibly look into the PDF specification and pull the text into an editor and then regenerate the file.

I am not familiar with the Google Docs API, but if anyone had a capability along these lines they might be a good place to start.

Comment: That is food for thought. I hadn't considered using something else to generate a PDF from which would give me an avenue to pursue.